# Are questions just about IPFS on-topic?

Tags: discussion

This question may need improvement
[Add file to IPFS using API](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4531/add-file-to-ipfs-using-api)

but it leads to this meta question of whether IPFS-only questions are on-topic.

Opinions?

Comment: Another [good ipfs-only question](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/10832/87).

Answer (score 5):

I'll probably stop asking these types of on-topic questions since the general answer could be:

*It should be handled by the community: if enough flag a question as off-topic, then there is probably a good reason for it.  If too many such questions keep getting flagged, then we discuss a more formal policy.*

Comment: I think also we should take anything that is Ethereum/Dapp/decentralized related. We will see if some Qs at really off topic they will be flagged. We should be more agile as this community starts.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say yes and no. For multiple reasons:

- Yes, because IPFS might become the successor of SWARM since the SWARM development is slow and still in very early stages.
- Yes, because IPFS content is a fundamental aspect of DApp development.
- No, because IPFS is not directly related Ethereum, Swarm and Whispter.

But that said, It's worth to rethink the scope of this Stack Exchange site somewhere in the near future, are decentralized systems (in general) on or off topic?; are smart-contract enabled blockchain systems (non-ethereum) on or off topic?

For now, **I would teach the OP about the site's scope** and **encourage her to put the question in a ethereum related setting**. I'm pretty sure it's about ethereum related dapp development, it's just not clearly stated.

Comment: I would be more liberal: If people ask about IPFS at the Ethereum site, they use it relative to Ethereum. They don't have to prove it. I want to try to answer such questions in order to learn about IPFS. It's practical to have them here

Comment: Same here. I'm interested in learning about the usage of IPFS with Ethereum.