# Ethereum Stack Exchange Summer Challenge 2016

Tags: discussion, meta, challenge, badges

I'm willing to put up a bounty to any user in here to earn the [Convention](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention) silver badge until end of July of 2016. This is a reward for **participating in our site's meta**. Currently only eth, murch and myself hold one. Let's change this. The rules are simple and there are only two:

- Earn the [Convention](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/68/convention) badge during the months of June or July 2016
- Have at least one answer on any question (needed to award the points*)

I am willing to put up 50xp of my points to anyone who makes the grade. You don't even have to acknowledge you are shooting for this, just show up, ask questions and take part in meta discussions.

A good place to start is maybe [the unanswered meta discussions page](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

**NOTE*: Please make sure your answer I award on is a good one, if you only have a crap answer, I'll hold the points until you have a good one worthy of the points :-)

Comment: After your other post about what's in and out I am pleased to find such a thoughtful community manager. Didn't answer because there was indeed so much to say. Thumbs up for the initiative I will participate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the winner is ... :)

[image: meta activity]