# Are questions about books and tutorials on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation, scope

This question:

- [Ethereum Tutorial for Beginners](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5952/105)

asks for a book and tutorials.

Are that kind of questions on-topic?

---

In case it is off-topic, can we have appropriate close reason for that kind of questions?

---

Related: [What is really on-topic for Ethereum Stack Exchange?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/306/105)

Comment: That question comes very close to being a request for a shopping recommendation.  Off-topic at almost every SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. From our off topic close reasons:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Exchange as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

I closed that thread.

Answer (score 2):

Since all relevant information for learning Ethereum should be freely available on line, questions looking for particularly good free and online sources of material should be on topic. I personally love when stackexchange is able to not only answer a question but provide a somewhat curated index to more reading materials.