# On Ethereum Classic usage

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, topic

After the recent Hardfork not only on a technical level but also on a [community level](https://np.reddit.com/r/EthereumClassic/) I think Ethereum Classic questions will be [well on topic](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/306/87) for our Q&A site. (If not, please use this thread to discuss pro & contra).

However, we need to find out how to distinguish Ethereum (Ether, ETH) questions from Ethereum Classic (Ether Classic?, ETC?, ETHC?) posts.

There is already the first tag [etc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etc) appearing. Now the question is:

- Is *Ethereum Classic* the official name? I also read about *Ethereum Core* and other suggestions.
- Is ETHC the official abbreviation? Or is it ETC? ETH-C?
- How are Ether called on the Ethereum Classic chain?
- Is [etc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etc) the best choice for Ethereum Classic? It could be misunderstood. What about [ethereum-classic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethereum-classic) or [ethc](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethc)?

Please try to leave any politics or dog fights out of this thread and use just reasonable arguments or try to gather facts or link official resources. This is only about the usage on Ethereum Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the network is Ethereum Classic, the currency Ether Classic, and the ticker ETC. (Or ETHC, but that didn't seem to make it as a symbol.)

I think the tag should be `ethereum-classic`. I don't think we would tag a bitcoin question `btc`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `ETC` is the most commonly used name that I've seen on the Etherium Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/ as well as most pool and exchanages that I've ssen. I'd assume that we'd want to keep it at `ETC` as well. And I think just tagging it with `ETC` should be sufficient.