# 2017 Graduation Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In tune with its [graduation](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/474/congratulations-ethereum-is-graduating), Ethereum is scheduled for an election [next week, July 3rd](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/election/1).In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/492/2017-graduation-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, July 3rd at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 7):

What keeps you coming back to the Ethereum Stack Exchange?  Things may be "hot" now, and what will keep you coming back when things "cool" down?

Answer (score 5):

From [On Ethereum Classic usage](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358/on-ethereum-classic-usage)

> ...Ethereum Classic questions will be well on topic...

Agree/disagree/ambivalent?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can help improve the site and sometimes this can be "clean up". What areas/s, if any, are you motivated or nags you to improve or clean up?

Answer (score 2):

Where do you stand on this?

[Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/470/should-we-discourage-questions-about-exchanges-trading-buying)

> ```
> Should we discourage questions about exchanges, trading, buying?
>
> ... How? :)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

What strengths do you think you would bring to being a moderator? Which of your "weaknesses" do you think would make it more difficult for you to being moderator?

Answer (score 0):

One of the very important things I would like to see with Eth SE would be to have a section for generic (and some targeted question) which will help new users and like currently, a discussion of PoS is going can be better structured. What do you think as a candidate on this?