# Are questions about Hyperledger Fabric on-topic?

Tags: discussion

**Should questions that are specifically confined to the workings of Hyperledger Fabric be on topic?**

Context:

- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/does-hyperledger-fabric-support-jason-rpc
- [Hyperledger Fabric - Is it a Blockchain Framework or Blockchain Platform?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31754/hyperledger-fabric-is-it-a-blockchain-framework-or-blockchain-platform)

Previous meta discussion: [What is really on-topic for Ethereum Stack Exchange?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/what-is-really-on-topic-for-ethereum-stack-exchange)

I can see that questions comparing Fabric to Ethereum *might* be useful to some extent, so could be considered on-topic, but IMO questions about Fabric that are in no way connected to Ethereum should be considered off-topic.

Note that we have the [hyperledger](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger) and [hyperledger-fabric](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger-fabric) tags.

Thoughts?

---

**Background:**

Hyperledger Fabric is one of the Hyperledger projects. It provides a plug-and-play framework for developing blockchain stuff. It doesn't support the EVM directly.

Hyperledger *Burrow* is another of their projects and includes an Apache-licensed Ethereum VM implementation.

(I'm unsure if Burrow is a sub-project of, and therefore built on top of, Fabric.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think questions about other blockchains that do not mention or involve some aspect of Ethereum, should be flagged off-topic for migrating them to the Bitcoin Stack Exchange, which appears to be the site for all other blockchains.

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour

> Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for
>   cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the
>   Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working
>   together to build a library of detailed answers to every question
>   about Cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple,
>   ZCash, Dogecoin, and NXT.
>
> Please note that Ethereum and Monero have launched their own Stack
>   Exchange sites.

Comment: Note that - at the time of writing - the Bitcoin community also doesn't accept questions about other cryptocurrencies anymore, let alone other blockchain technologies.