# Is Ethereum Stack Exchange a Q&A for Enterprise-Based/Fork versions of Ethereum as well?

Tags: discussion

Is Ethereum Stack Exchange a Q&A/Forum for Enterprise-Based/Fork versions of Ethereum as well?

Nathan Aw

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs to meta site of Ethereum Stack Exchange

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Though there'll likely always be some topics that are in a grey area... e.g. How far from the base implementation does a fork have to deviate before it's considered too dissimilar to qualify as on-topic?

See: [What is really on-topic for Ethereum Stack Exchange?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306/what-is-really-on-topic-for-ethereum-stack-exchange?rq=1)

Comment: hey richard thanks for your response.